# Cannot get functions from apollo-server-express

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

I am following the tutorial and trying to start node server and i cant import this to functions from Apollo package

```
const {graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress} = require('apollo-server-express'); // here i importing fucntions
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // import parser
const cors = require('cors'); // import cors
const express = require('express'); // import cors
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

const port = 9000; // define port

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers}); // init shcema

const app = express();
app.use(cors(), bodyParser.json());
app.use('/graphql', graphqlExpress({schema})); // is not a function
app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({endpointUrl: '/graphql'})); // is not a function
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on the port ${port}`));
```

When i starting the server if fails due to "graphqlExpress is not a function", and when it commented and the server restarted the same thing about graphiqlExpress. Maybe the tutorial i am following is outdated and apollo-server-express doesnt provide such functions anymore?

Answer (score 17):

Apollo Server 2.0 introduced a number of breaking changes with the intention of simplifying setup. There's a [migration guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration-two-dot.html) in the documentation that outlines the changes. If all you need is a GraphQL server, getting started can be as simple as this:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.listen()
```

Note that the above simply uses the `apollo-server` package. `apollo-server-express` still exists if you want to continue to utilize Apollo as express middleware instead of running Apollo as a "standalone" server.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const app = require('express')();

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
app.listen({ port: 3000 })
```

The new API eliminates the need to separately import and implement additional middleware like `body-parser` or `cors`. [Read the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/server.html) for more information about how to configure your Apollo Server instance.