# While using Typescript - TypeError: graphqlExpress is not a function

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am using GraphQL with my typescript am getting the following error

```
const { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } = require("apollo-server-express"); 
//import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from "apollo-server-express"; (commented because it doesnt support ts)

server.ts:31
app.use("/graphql", bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ schema }));
                                       ^
TypeError: graphqlExpress is not a function
```

Since apollo is not supporting import am using the require. But not it says its not a function.

Comment: Which version of `apollo-server-express` are you using? Even `1.0.2` had TypeScript support. `graphqlExpress` does not exist anymore in `2.0`. See eg.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233663/cannot-get-functions-from-apollo-server-express

Comment: Please refer to the [repo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-express) for additional examples.